# Getting wrong size of physics body in Retina device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have made some physics body using Physics body. But i am getting 2x size body in retina devices. I am not getting why this is happening.Can any one guide me in this? I am attaching images for ipad and ipad-retina devices.

Image from ipad-nonretina device. In non-retina physics body is working fine.
[image]

Image from ipad-retina.Physics texture is coming in 2x size.[image]

I made physics shape in physicEditor and then i used GB2ShapeCache to set fixture.

**

```
[[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache]
     addFixturesToBody:tireBody2 forShapeName:@"Tire"];
```

**

Comment: show us the code where you set up the shapes. Common mistake is to apply cc_contentscalefactor to anything physics-related, though here it seems only some shapes are affected and they are not exactly 2x scaled in bith dimensions, plus they seem offset. Impossible to diagnose without any code.

Comment: try to draw bodybox according to the sprite size the it will not happen

Comment: I used multiplier in GB2ShapeCache while fixture is given to body and now problem solved.

Comment: I guess it is because of variation in point system, as in retina display 1 point is equal to 2 pixels and that's why fixture was coming in 2x size.